# angular-cli build with --watch doesn't watch

Tags: angular-cli

I faced a problem, on Ubuntu 17.04 `@angular/cli@1.3.2` command `ng build --watch` exits after it builds app (successfully) and doesn't start to watch. `ng serve` though works fine and starts watcher.

The most similar problems I found were solved with setting output path via `-op` option or `outDir` property in `.angular-cli.json`, none of these seem to help in my case. Any ideas of what possibly can be the reason to that?

**Update**

My bad, `ng serve` just didn't stop process, watcher still wasn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the update, it became clear that the problem is with watching generally and not with specific command so I found out that the problem is with Linux `Inotify` watches limit which can be expanded in either way:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p --system
```

or

```
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

The problem with this is that limit resets on computer restart.

Sources:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2356#issuecomment-278298550

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2389#issuecomment-250964095